# How do I override a SASS variable with anotehr value based on a CSS selector?

Tags: css, variables, sass, scope, selector

I am trying to override a SASS variable like so:

```
.component {
  $background: red;

  // Variations
  &.component--blue {
    $background: blue;
  }

  &.component--green {
    $background: green;
  }

  // lots of styling in-between
  a {
    background: $background;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="component">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>

<div class="component component--green">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately with the above code the a tag with in the component always has a green background. I would have expected to be red on the first and green on the second. Am I missing something?
I have looked up the documentation here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#scope

As far as I can see this should be possible, but maybe not..

Could anybody enlighten me?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since a variable can hold only one value at a time, the $background variable is taking the latest value assigned to it.

I would suggest using below code:

`$background-red: red;
 $background-blue: blue;
 $background-green: green`

and then use the following

```
 &.component--blue {
    background: $background-blue;
  }

 &.component--green {
    background: $background-green;
  }
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you **cannot** change variables following CSS conditions because they are **compiled before** any browser CSS interpretation.

Take a look at [CSS VAR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) which are a perfect alternative in your case. `var()` are well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_custom-property_var).